# google chart api qr code with line break at the end

Tags: qr-code, line-breaks

Im need to create qr code with line break (\r\n) at the end of the text
im trying to achive this with google chart api like this 
`%0D%0A` - is the url encoded values for `\r\n`

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=qr_1a146dbd-c799-41c3-ad3d-ce50a5804e49%0D%0A&choe=UTF-8&chld=H
```

but a can see that google trims last line breaks
if i try same text with multiple line breaks then qr code will be exactly te same

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=qr_1a146dbd-c799-41c3-ad3d-ce50a5804e49%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&choe=UTF-8&chld=H
```

is there a way to stop google from triming the text?
or how can i add line break at the end?

correct qr code should be line this 
[image: qr code]

Answer (score 0):

as a somewhat temporary solution I found that adding a %02 after %0d%0a will allow the line breaks to not be removed